# What would cause a supermassive plateau that sticks out of the ocean

Tags: science-based, earth-like, geography

On an Earth-like planet, there is a massive plateau, standing more than 1km high, and the breadth of a continent in the middle of an otherwise ocean planet.

I know there are climactic issues to this, but instead of hand-waving it, the best answer would explain the processes that created this steep, high continental mass.  High-level, and not magic and no humans.

On the continent (size of, say, Africa) is most biomes - desert, forest, lakes, rivers sourced by artesian springs/rain, and then cascade off the sides of the continent.  There are plants and animals.

This is for a young adult novel, so I am not using the hard-science tag.

Comment: So, this is a continent, like Australia, but with no mountains? And seawalls all the way around?

Comment: Massive tectonic plate activity in the past combined with a core of very hard rock and softer stuff around it which corroded/broke away to leave only sheer rock

Comment: @Samuel - precisely; there are some mountains but the significant difference is that it is a sheer ~1km cliff drop from the continent to the ocean.  No humans.

Comment: How old of a planet are you looking for? Could it have had other continents now past?

Comment: @TheNate - I'm not fussed about age, but I suspect it would be older than our Earth.  I'm open to any interpretation, though.

Answer (score 8):

**Massive glaciation**

Most continents are already shaped somewhat like plateaus. They slope gently towards the continental margins, before fairly abruptly dropping down to the ocean floor. In profile, they look something like this:

[image]

The issue is that most of that plateau-like shape is hidden by water. However, if you get *rid* of a lot of that water, your continent will start to look more plateau-like.

Massive glaciation would help achieve this. If a significant portion of the planet's oceans are bound up in glaciers, the corresponding lowering of sea levels will make your continents more plateau like. Planets which previously had a steep continental slope with little to no continental shelf will appear as plateaus sticking out of the ocean. Africa is an example of a continent that would appear more plateau-like in this case, while the west coast of South America would also appear to rise sharply out of the ocean.

Comment: This is a good idea, but with only one continent the size of Africa, the only place the glaciation could go would be on that continent itself.  The continent would have to be covered with ice roughly 20 km thick in order to be raised 1 km above sea level.

Comment: Good point, I had missed the whole 'there is only one continent' bit. Unless there exist ice caps that rest on bedrock, this won't work (Unless the continent is reaaaaaaly snowy.).

Answer (score 4):

**A super-massive [pumice raft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumice_raft).**

Created by continual ocean-based volcanic activity, you could have an increasingly large floating island forming, especially if your planetary ocean did not have significant tidal/current action to shift the raft around.

This might be the most feasible on a planet with low gravity; not sure you could get it more than 1 km high otherwise -- you're dealing with displacement vs. mass physics at that point.  The density of the pumice would also be a factor in how buoyant it is.  Pumice rafts reported from 2012 volcanic eruptions were reported to be ~300 miles long & ~30 miles wide, but only riding about 2 feet from the surface.

As per my other answer, given enough time and initial planetary biodiversity, the pumice raft would hopefully be seeded with life.

Answer (score 3):

Conan Doyle used real-world tepuis for his Lost World story, and though the Earth ones aren't as much surface area as you're looking for, the geology and height otherwise seem about right:

[image: Roraima, apprently?]

http://www.amusingplanet.com/2013/05/tabletop-mountains-or-tepuis-of.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tepui

Though they're lofted from jungles rather than from the sea floor, it might not be too much of a stretch to theorize some swift climate shifting to submerge a lowland with these features, and they definitely fit your 1k height requirement.  The morphology section of the Wikipedia link should give you enough research information to extrapolate your version, I think?

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia on how plateaus are formed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau):

> Plateaus can be formed by a number of processes, including upwelling
>   of volcanic magma, extrusion of lava, and erosion by water and
>   glaciers. Magma rises from the mantle causing the ground to swell
>   upward, in really large, flat areas of rock that are uplifted.
>   Plateaus can also be built up by lava spreading outward from cracks
>   and weak areas in the crust. Plateaus can also be formed by the
>   erosional processes of glaciers on mountain ranges, leaving them
>   sitting between the mountain ranges. Water can also erode mountains
>   and other landforms down into plateaus. Computer modeling studies
>   suggest that high plateaus may also be partially a result from the
>   feedback between tectonic deformation and dry climatic conditions
>   created at the lee side of growing orogens.

I don't see any particular reason why these natural processes could not produce a continent as you describe--especially if the right combination of plate tectonics and volcanic activity occurred.

There are already quite large plateaus in the world: the [Tibetan Plateau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_Plateau) is about 2,500,000 square kilometers (about 1/12 the size of Africa) and is 4.5 times higher above sea level, on average, than your mythical continent.

Answer (score 1):

A massive large igneous province.
the Columbia plateau is one example of such a thing, probably caused by hotspot as opposed to continental rifting, then glaciation.
not perfect, but as close as I could surmise.

Answer (score 0):

**The low-velocity impact of a large asteroid in the distant past.**

The feasibility of this would heavily depend on physics dealing with the size of the asteroid & its speed, as well as the depth of the planet's oceans.

- **Too fast?** -- It would break up into a bunch of small pieces upon impact.
- **Too large**? -- It'd possibly vaporize most of the ocean or break the planet itself into pieces.
- **Ocean too deep**? -- It wouldn't stick up out of the ocean far enough.

Given enough time and initial planetary biodiversity, the barren asteroid could be seeded with the biomes you describe.

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer. You should flesh it out.

Comment: More like the *landing* of a very large asteroid, yeah?

Comment: @AndreiROM: Hah wow you're fast!  I was just about to; I didn't want to get scooped on my answer. ;)

Comment: This would most likely just create a really big crater, no? Think about the [Chicxulub crater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicxulub_crater). That was an ocean impact, and look at the effects it caused. Anything big enough to stick out would absolutely cause chaos in the planet. I don't think it would work.

Comment: @HDE226868: Quite possibly, physics is not my strong suit.  I think it would heavily depend on how slowly an asteroid could impact and yet still be a naturally occurring celestial body.

Comment: @HDE226868:  That impact was presumably at a velocity high enough to completely destroy the asteroid.  That's the big question -- can something big enough come in slowly enough to leave anything behind?  Mineral / metallurgical composition & general structure might make a difference.  As for the rest, would such an impact cause chaos?  Certainly!  Would the planet recover ecologically?  Ours sure did.  ;)

Comment: Anything hitting the Earth from outside of Earth's orbit will be moving at least the Earth's escape velocity when it hits the atmosphere (unless it's powered). That's 11.2 km/s. That will cause *quite* the dent.

Comment: @JoeBloggs why is that? Should it not be possible for it to travel at little more than the speed the earth orbits the sun? Then this delta-v would be the impact velocity, would it not? (some gravitational acceleration will be added, but will that be that much?)

Comment: @Burki: I tend to think of it like this: If there's just me and the Earth, in order for me to be no longer captured by the Earth's gravity (ie: floating just ahead of it), I have to get up to escape velocity or I'll be dragged back down eventually. If I almost make it but then get dragged back down, then the speed I hit at will be the same speed I almost left at, because I'll get accelerated back at the same rate I was fighting against all the way up.

Comment: @JoeBloggs: Sure, the bolide will cause a substantial impact crater -- but will it leave anything behind, or will it just get obliterated in the impact?  That's the million dollar question: is there a realistic asteroid composition that would survive the impact, at the prerequisite size?

Comment: @wingman4l7: at those kind of velocities metals splash and the air underneath the rock gets heated to a plasma. I can't think of any natural material that can survive that without shattering into dust on impact or burying itself in the crust (Newtons impactor estimations apply here). I like the answer, don't get me wrong, and since hard science isn't a tag here: why not!

Comment: @Wingman4l7 The energy of entry from space is sufficient to melt anything out there.  I think it's even enough to vaporize anything.  Properly protected spacecraft survive not because their heat shield can take it, but because most of the energy goes into the atmosphere instead, the shield is there to protect the craft against the energy it absorbs from the superheated air it's flying through.

Answer (score 0):

Have a smallish tectonic plate, with two massive plates moving towards and sliding under it, one from each side.

The approaching plates would combine to lift up the central smaller one. You'd end up with a lot of volcanic activity and mountain-forming at each join and the smaller plate potentially hoisted right out of the ocean as the other two went under it.